# Access "subject variability" from a repeated measures ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

**I run a one way repeated measures ANOVA, and I would like to access the subject variability.**

In a repeated measures ANOVA, the error (sum of squares) can be decomposed:
$SS_{total} = SS_{treatment} + SS_{between~subjects} + SS_{error}$

We are usually interested in $SS_{treatment}$ to measure the effect of our factor, but the variance explained by subject variability is also interesting.

Is there a way to easily access it?

**Below is a minimal example.**

`aov` gives the following output:

- `mean_score` is the dependent variable
- `dog.id` identify the subjects
- `leg` is the factors (treatment) (each `dog.id` is measured 4 times, for the 4 legs)

```
> summary(aov(mean_score ~ leg + Error( dog.id/leg), data=control_2 ) )

Error: dog.id
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 14  696.9   49.78               

Error: dog.id:leg
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
leg        3   47.0  15.665   3.026 0.0399 *
Residuals 42  217.4   5.176                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Alternatively, using the `ez` package, this output is available:

```
>  ezANOVA(
+     control_2
+     dv=.(mean_score),
+     wid=.(dog.id),
+     within=.(leg),
+     detailed = T,
+   )

$ANOVA
       Effect DFn DFd        SSn      SSd         F            p p<.05        ges
1 (Intercept)   1  14 4575.68446 696.8758 91.923957 1.569623e-07     * 0.83346250
2         leg   3  42   46.99517 217.4101  3.026227 3.993833e-02     * 0.04888806

$`Mauchly's Test for Sphericity`
  Effect         W          p p<.05
2    leg 0.4122229 0.04681839     *

$`Sphericity Corrections`
  Effect      GGe      p[GG] p[GG]<.05       HFe      p[HF] p[HF]<.05
2    leg 0.751553 0.05710458           0.9030498 0.04589048         *
```

Thank you!